# Binding options inside other options services.Configure<>()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, configuration

Imagine I have the following settings in appsettings.json :

```json
  {
  "OtherSettings" : {
    "id" : 3
  },
  
  "Needed" : {
    "Database" : {
      "ConnectionString" : "abc123"
    },

    "Interval" : {
      "is_active" = true,
      "in_seconds" = "15" 
    }
  } 
}
```

For the Database section I've got an class which is `DatabaseSettings` with property `ConnectionString`.

And for the Interval section I've got the class `IntervalSettings`.

If I would like to bind all those settings inside `Needed` to an class `NeededSettings`, what property do I need and how would I bind the options for the Database class with Dependency Injection ? Currently I am doing this with:

```cs
services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>Configuration.GetSection("Needed:Database"));
services.Configure<IntervalSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Needed:Interval"));
```

So I am doing this with 2 lines, but I want to do it in 1 line and bind all the settings to the new class `NeededSettings`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove these two lines and add:

```
services.Configure<NeededSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Needed"));
```

and use `NeededSettings` in all places you used `DatabaseSettings` and `IntervalSetttings`.

Edit:

```
public class NeededSettings{
    public DatabaseSettings Database {get;set;}
    public IntervalSettings Interval {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: But what properties would this ```NeededSettings``` class have ?

Comment: @schweppes0x see updated version of comment.